# Javascript REST API with body in GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, get, request

I'm working in Javascript (frontend) and have a colleague working in the backend with NodeJS.
When **calling a GET request**, he asks me to put **the data in the body**, but I could not figure out how to do that. (If I use this code to a POST request, it works fine).
Could you tell me if this is possible and how to do it? He says that it is possible, but I've googled a lot and could not find the correct way to do that.
ERROR that I get: **"Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body."**

```
    let URL = "http://localhost:3000/verifyUser";
    let token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NjJDMTRBNk";
    
    fetch(URL, {
        method: request,
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user: 'Carlos6',
            password: '543534543',
            email: "algo6@gmail.com"
        }),
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'auth-token': token
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        return Promise.reject(response);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn('Something went wrong.', error);
    });
```

Comment: So GET requests are not supposed to have a body.  So, go back to your colleague and straighten that out with them. If the data has to be in a body, use a POST or a PUT.

Comment: Thank you! Finally talk to him and he is going to change the method to POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using HTTP GET and sending a body.

If you want to send a body (JSON) you should use the PUT and POST.

The best will probably be to:

- change your client code to `method: "PUT"`
- change the server to access PUT request

If you want to know which one to chose look at this question:
( [PUT vs. POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest))

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to send a request with a body then you should make a POST-request and not a GET one. GET-request cannot have a body by its nature and primary goal.
All params of GET-request must be indicated in the URL itself only.